# Laravel 5 Authenticator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement socialite but I am getting an error relating to the authenticator class. My app can not find it.

This is the code in my controller

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository as UserRepository;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;

class AuthenticateUser {

    private $users;
    private $socialite;
    private $auth;
        public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Socialite $socialite, Authenticator $auth)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    public function execute($hasCode)
    {
        if ( ! $hasCode ) return $this->getAuthorisationFirst();

        $user = $this->socialite->drivers('google')->user();

        dd($user);
    }

private function getAuthorisationFirst()
{
    return $this->socialite->driver('google')->redirect();
}

}
```

The error I receive is

ReflectionException in Container.php line 833: Class Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that with laravel 5 the authenticator is now called Guard

> The Authenticator was renamed to Guard. In the AuthenticateUser.php file rename 'use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator;' to 'use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;' and don't forget to also change it in constructor function too" –

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I ran the auto dump command and replaced the line with yours. I still have the same error

Comment: Does the 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator' exists in folder structure?

Comment: I can't seem to find it in the Vendor. only the Illuminate/html folder. Do I need to add something to my composer.json

Comment: I don't know the socialite package. But if you've done the install description it should be enough.

Comment: It seems that with laravel 5 the authenticator is now called Guard "The Authenticator was renamed to Guard. In the AuthenticateUser.php file rename 'use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticator;' to 'use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;' and don't forget to also change it in constructor function too"

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks. Want to change your answer so I can mark it as done :)